# DataFlow job failed with Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Requested deidentify

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-kms

Following an official video from GCP on YouTube ([https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kc7_wDDctAc&list=PLIivdWyY5sqK9j4_JkC8j1mY4JEGgLdcD&index=6][1]).

I am trying to replicate Masking from CSV and write in BigQuery with a Cryptographic key but my DataFlow job throwing many of these errors even if the deidentify template is correctly configured and the path it`s also correct. The only difference is that I can't do it globally so I am done in the same setting in europe region.

> 2023-11-09 12:48:13.870 EET Error message from worker:
> com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException:
> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Requested deidentify
> template not found.
> com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:90)
> com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:41)
> com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:86)
> com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:66)
> com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
> com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:84)
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1127)
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31)
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1286)
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:1055)
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:807)
> io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:578)
> io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:548)
> io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
> com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$ReleasingClientCall$1.onClose(ChannelPool.java:541)
> io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
> io.grpc.census.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:814)
> io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
> io.grpc.census.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:494)
> io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:489)
> io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:453)
> io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:486)
> io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:567)
> io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:71)
> io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:735)
> io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:716)
> io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
> io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
> Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Requested
> deidentify template not found.
> io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:539)
> io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:548)
> io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
> com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$ReleasingClientCall$1.onClose(ChannelPool.java:541)
> io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
> io.grpc.census.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:814)
> io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
> io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
> io.grpc.census.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:494)
> io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:489)
> io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:453)
> io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:486)
> io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:567)
> io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:71)
> io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:735)
> io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:716)
> io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
> io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

If there is another specific approach for regional or Europe please let me know. I tried to do it from Python with many examples from official documentation but nothing helped me.
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kc7_wDDctAc&list=PLIivdWyY5sqK9j4_JkC8j1mY4JEGgLdcD&index=6

Comment: Can you check if all necessary APIs in GCP have been [enabled](https://cloud.google.com/dlp?hl=en)? Can you try with the global path according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/dlp-text-to-bigquery), Data Masking/Tokenization from Cloud Storage to BigQuery template does not support a regional path for de-identification template location. Only a global path is supported. Let me know if this solves your issue or not.